# BigNumber issue — RequireJS and Web3

Tags: web3js, bignumber, requirejs

Here's my main.js file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min',
        web3: 'lib/web3',
        MainController: 'controllers/MainController',
        mainService: 'services/mainService'

    },
    shim: {
        "angular": {
            exports: "angular"
        }
    }
});

require(['web3', 'angular', 'utils/init'],
    function() {    
        web3 = new Web3();
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);       
    }
);
```

So, I've succesfully connected to Geth, because I can obtain my account address using `web3.eth.getAccounts(...)`.

The problems arise when I try to check my balance:

```
var getBalance = function(address){ 
    web3.eth.getBalance(address, gotBalance);   
    function gotBalance(error, wei){
        console.log(wei);               
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried calling some other methods that use BigNumber library under the hood and I get the same error.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that both **requireJS** and **web3** declare variables **define** and **require** in *global scope*. Naming collision is the cause. I've managed to make my code to work, but it's an ugly solution and I will post something better here later. If you want to learn about renaming these variables check out RequireJS [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html)

Answer (score 2):

Calls in **web3** [always](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js) return **BigNumber** instances for every number returning method.

The fix is to avoid the check and treat all returned values as **BigNumber**s.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of how to create an instance of **BigNumber**:

```
var nr = new BigNumber("10");
```

and all available [methods](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/):

```
nr.abs                  nr.decimalPlaces        nr.equals               nr.isInteger            nr.lte                  nr.pow                  nr.sub                  nr.toNumber             
nr.absoluteValue        nr.div                  nr.floor                nr.isNaN                nr.minus                nr.precision            nr.times                nr.toPower              
nr.add                  nr.divToInt             nr.greaterThan          nr.isNeg                nr.mod                  nr.round                nr.toDigits             nr.toPrecision          
nr.c                    nr.dividedBy            nr.greaterThanOrEqualTo nr.isNegative           nr.modulo               nr.s                    nr.toExponential        nr.toString             
nr.ceil                 nr.dividedToIntegerBy   nr.gt                   nr.isZero               nr.mul                  nr.sd                   nr.toFixed              nr.trunc                
nr.cmp                  nr.dp                   nr.gte                  nr.lessThan             nr.neg                  nr.shift                nr.toFormat             nr.truncated            
nr.comparedTo           nr.e                    nr.isFinite             nr.lessThanOrEqualTo    nr.negated              nr.sqrt                 nr.toFraction           nr.valueOf              
nr.constructor          nr.eq                   nr.isInt                nr.lt                   nr.plus                 nr.squareRoot           nr.toJSON
```

To import **BigNumbers** in your code install package **bignumbers.js**:

```
# npm install -g bignumber.js
```

and then include it in your source file:

```
var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');
```

Comment: Treat all returned values as `BigNumber`s and use their methods to work with their value (see the edited answer).

Comment: I don't have access to BigNumber function. To be precise, I don't know how to import it from web3.js file. It's not in global scope

Comment: var BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

Comment: I've added `BigNumber = require('bignumber.js'); console.log(BigNumber);` after `web3.setProvider(...)`. In my logs I now have an empty object. And the error persists if I query my balance. Note, that the error doesn't come from my code, it's an error inside the web3. It's as if BigNumber wasn't initiated in the web3 itself for some reason.

Comment: If the module got included and didn't throw an error it means that it is present. Can you try to do the following: create a contract that has an integer returning method and call the method?

Comment: Nope, it still gives me an error when I try to invoke an integer returning function `web3.js:1059 Uncaught TypeError: BigNumber is not a constructor`

Comment: also when I try to deploy a contract(code worked before with MetaMask) I get this: `Error: exec: "solc": executable file not found in %PATH%`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43728/discussion-between-sebi-and-eugene-epifanov).

Comment: as it turns out, the problem is in naming collision. I've answered my question. Please check it out! Thank you very much, good sir!!!